# Tensorflow Object-detection api

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, precision-recall

How can we draw ground truth boundary box with predicted boundary box at the time of inference by making use of tensorflow object detection api?

How to calculate precision,recall & mAP for object detection using SSD model with KITTI like dataset?

Comment: Have a look at this https://medium.com/@sshleifer/how-to-finetune-tensorflows-object-detection-models-on-kitti-self-driving-dataset-c8fcfe3258e9

Comment: @Srikanth Thanks for your guidelines.....it really worked for me. I have made some changes & able to draw ground truth

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you see the mentioned following websites :

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html

if you use a pre-trained model which there are a large list of them in the TensorFlow model garden zoo, you can customize the model as well. another advantage of using TensorFlow models is that the precision of such models are measured previously and you don't need to measure them again as you see in the below picture:

[image]

but for the second part of your question, I can say that you can download the LabelImage GUI and use it to create bounding boxes on your train images and feed them to the TensorFlow object-detection-API

Answer (score 0):

How can we draw a ground truth boundary box with a predicted bounding box at the time of inference by making use of TensorFlow object detection API?

Ans: you can draw a bounding box by XML file referred to the image by `xml.etree.ElementTree` function [Extract XML coordinates](https://www.kaggle.com/code/mtszkw/reading-sample-image-and-bounding-boxes-from-xml)  if you want to draw a ground truth bounding box in the predicted image you can extract xmin,xmax,ymin and ymax in an XML file after that use cv2.rectangle to draw ground truth bounding box in the predicted image

How to calculate precision,recall & mAP for object detection using SSD model with KITTI like dataset?
Ans: in TF2 can use `!python model_main_tf2.py --alsologtostderr --model_dir='___' --pipeline_config_path='____' --checkpoint_dir='____'` or you can validated by yourself, for example, create the function to calculate IOU